# nested json by pig not giving correct output

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

```
{"query":"32 gb memory card and pen drive","queryObj":{"32 Gb memory card and Pen drive":34359738368,"32 gb memory card and pen drive":6872838602707},"implicitIntent":[],"textualIntent":[{"attributes":{"attributes":[{"field":{"name":"store"},"value":"Memory Cards & Readers","properties":{"storeId":"zzf","storePath":"tyy/4mr/zzf","isLeaf":false}} ]}}]}
```

I want `query` and `field-name` and `value` for this `json` using `pig`. So I have written following script:

```
G = LOAD 'quattr.json' USING JsonLoader('query:chararray, textualIntent: {(attributes:(attributes:{(field: (name:chararray),value:chararray)}))}') ;
```

but this giving only query output, not other two fields:

```
(32 gb memory card and pen drive,)
```

May anyone help to figure out problem? Thanks

Comment: The schema given to JsonLoader must match all the fields in the same order as in the data.

Comment: @franklinsijo Can we give first starting required fields in order, if we didn't requires last fields.

Comment: No, It is not possible with JsonLoader. For such scenario, you can try [elephant-bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird)

Comment: @franklinsijo Thanks. facing problem in using elephant-bird.  [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864815/elephantbird-registered-still-showing-error-2998).