# elephantbird registered still showing error 2998

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

```
grunt> register '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/json-simple-1.1.1.jar' 
grunt> register '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar' 
grunt> register '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar' 
grunt> register '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar' 

grunt> load_tweets = LOAD '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/quattr.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
2017-01-26 07:16:29,631 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

grunt> load1_tweets = LOAD '/home/piyush/Desktop/pro/product.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
2017-01-26 07:17:47,740 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Could not initialize class com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader
```

I registered all required jar files and then load two different json. Both show `error 2998` with load1_tweets an additional error that `Could not initialize class` as shown above. How to reslove this error.

Getting following error in the logfile:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoBaseLoadFunc.<clinit>(LzoBaseLoadFunc.java:36)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:651)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1336)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1324)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:5184)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3515)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1791)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1764)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:707)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1075)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I am sure the `JsonLoader` you are using is present in `elephant-bird-pig.jar`. Could you try re-registering jars, also check for access issues!

Comment: Yes i tried. Still showing same error.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this scenario, but unable to. Works for me. What is the pig version?

Comment: @franklinsijo Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530)

Comment: No issues with 0.16.0 as well. I believe this is more of a classpath issue than pig. Can you check whether you have multiple/conflicting jars for slf4j in your classpath?

Comment: `echo $CLASSPATH
/home/piyush/Downloads/slf4j-1.7.22.jar
`

Comment: I understand that you have this jar additionally in your downloads folder. Can you remove this from the classpath and try.

Comment: Still showing same error.

Comment: `ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
Details at logfile: /home/piyush/pig_1485760497865.log
`

Comment: Now classpath is empty. How to check multiple/conflicting jars for slf4j.

Comment: There is no Hadoop. I am running on local mode.

Comment: The packages of Hadoop, Pig will contain this jar in their lib directory. You might get this error when Pig is not able to get hold of this jar or there is a conflict. But do you have any version of hadoop downloaded and not running?

Comment: yes @franklinsijo. I had Hadoop downloaded, but not installed.

Comment: Yes extracted. VERSION="3.11.0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134487/discussion-between-piyush-balwani-and-franklinsijo).